# How to recover the ParserRuleContext for a specific line and character position with antlr4?

Tags: c++, antlr4

Once I have initialised the parser, lexer and obtained the translationUnit context, how can I jump directly to the (closest) ParserRuleContext that contains a specific line and character position in antlr4 (CPP runtime) ?

Usually I m using the `Listener` pattern to walk through the translationUnit context. In every visited context, I can obtain the corresponding line and character position of a context using the following code :

```
antlr4::Token* tokenclass = _tokenstream->get(myContext->getSourceInterval().a); // use ".b" if end of interval is needed 
size_t CharPositionStartInLine = tokenclass->getCharPositionInLine();       
size_t LineStart = tokenclass->getLine();
```

I would like to perform the opposite: to obtain a token from a specific line and char position, and then to obtain the (first) parent context. Is it possible ?

I think I can achieve what I want (i.e to find a context based on line and character position) by checking every line and character position of `context` inside the function `enterEveryRule(antlr4::ParserRuleContext* context)` but it seems overcomplicated. So is there an easier way to recover the ParserRuleContext for a specific line/character position ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is pretty simple. A `ParserRuleContext` contains start and stop tokens with positioning information. Hence it is easy to tell if a rule context includes a specific position. Start with the parse tree root and iterate over its children. Find the one that includes this position (overlap is not possible). Continue with that node and its children until you find a terminal node, which is the one you are looking for. If for a given node no child includes the given position then use that node instead.

In the [MySQL Workbench Sources](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench) there's a C++ implementation for [`terminalFromPosition`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/mysql/MySQLRecognizerCommon.cpp#L271) and [`contextFromPosition`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/mysql/MySQLRecognizerCommon.cpp#L315). The first function takes a line/column pair and strives to always return a terminal (even if there's none directly at the given position), while the latter uses a character index and implements the approach exactly as I mentioned in the previous paragraph.